# Recursive Bubble Sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, bubble-sort

I am trying to write a Recursive Bubble sort in Java and I'm getting an Index Out of Bounds Exception. What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this error?
Here is my code:

```
public static  <T extends Comparable< ? super T>>
    void sort(T [] a){
    T tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i].compareTo(a[i+1])>0){
            tmp = a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=tmp;
            sort(a);
        }
        System.out.println("i:"+i+" "+a[i]);

    }
```

Also, even tho it sorts the array and I get the error at the end, it is printing all of the steps, how do I make it print the last final sorted array?
Is probably a simple answer but my brain is fried right now and can't think straight.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The loop should stop when `i < a.length-1` , because in your code you access the position `i+1`, and when `i == a.length - 1` then `i+1` will be trying to access an element off the end of the array that doesn't exist - hence, out of bounds.

Comment: Perfect, that helped. Didn't realized it until now. How do I fix the printing though?

Comment: You can use [Arrays.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object\[\])) to print the sorted contents at the end.

Comment: How would u do that without importing Arrays?

Comment: @fgualda87 - Not sure I follow you. Do you not want to use the `util.Arrays` class?

Comment: Importing Arrays is the easiest way, otherwise you'll have to implement your own printing method. I don't know if it helps, but you could also write `java.util.Arrays.toString()` - no explicit import declaration

Comment: @fgualda87 imports are free in java and you also could use java.util.Arrays.toString (i.e. use the explicit identifier)

Comment: Ok, I did put it that way, but it is printing it out a few times. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: If you only need to print the sorted array, call Arrays.toString() on the value returned from `sort()` _after_ you call it, in the place where you call it for the first time - not inside the `sort()` method

Comment: Well, the sort is void so nothing is returned. And I only call it from the driver where I test the method. The idea is to print it somehow inside the method.

Comment: @fgualda87 - The problem with doing anything once is that you're using a recursive method, which means it's calling itself. If you want the method to be in charge of printing the sorted contents only once, you'll need an outer method that's called first, which then calls the recursive sort, and prints the results afterward.

Comment: OK, it's void. But since you're sorting the array in place, you could print the array you passed to the method after calling the method, in pseudocode: String[] a = {}; sort(a); print(a);

Answer (score 5):

You've written your loop so that `i` gets as bit as `a.length - 1`. Then you are trying to access `a[i+1]`, which is an out-of-bounds index when `i == a.length - 1`. Lower your loop's limit by 1.

Comment: How would you do the print statement though?

Comment: @fgualda87 - After the loop exits, call `System.out.println("i:"+(a.length-1)+" "+a[a.length-1]);`

Comment: No, that doesn't give me anything. It prints out a couple of times the index of the last number and the value of it. The problem is that since it recursive, and there is a print statement in it, it prints multiple times, maybe I should create another post for that.

Comment: @fgualda87 - Another post would be the right way to go. I didn't get what your print problem was, and it seems like a different problem from the topic of this post.

Answer (score 2):

The upper limit should be length-1

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 public static void bubbleSort(Object[] source, int fromIndex, int endIndex){
            if(fromIndex==endIndex){
                return;
            }
            else{
                if(((Comparable) source[fromIndex]).compareTo(source [fromIndex+1])>0){
                    Object temp=source[fromIndex];
                    source[fromIndex]=source[fromIndex+1];
                    source[fromIndex+1]=temp;
                }
                bubbleSort(source,fromIndex+1,endIndex);
            }
            bubbleSort(source,fromIndex,endIndex-1);
        }
```